# XPages: How to disable a button in a repeat control

Tags: javascript, xpages

i'm using a repeat control in my XPage which contains some repeated buttons.

How can i get hold of individual buttons or fade out a particulat button after its been clicked?
i have tried the below code on the onClick even of the Clientside but it did not work

```
var id = dojo.query("[id='ActionBtn']")[0];
id.setDisabled(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the client side id with `#{id:ActionBtn}` and use it to get the button element to disable it:

```
document.getElementById("#{id:ActionBtn}").disabled=true
```

or to hide it after clicking

```
document.getElementById("#{id:ActionBtn}").style.visibility='hidden'
```

or

```
document.getElementById("#{id:ActionBtn}").style.display='none'
```

Example:

```
<xp:repeat
    id="repeat1"
    rows="30">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:[1,2,3,4]}]]></xp:this.value>
    <xp:button
        value="Label"
        id="ActionBtn">
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onclick"
            submit="false">
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
                  document.getElementById("#{id:ActionBtn}").style.display='none'
            ]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <br />
</xp:repeat>
```

Comment: but i like to disable one from the button and not all , how do i get the index of ActionBtn[0]

Comment: As the button is in a repeat control every button gets its own id. You get the id with `#{id:ActionBtn}`

Comment: I added my test example: only the clicked button disappears.

Comment: Good day Sir, base on my above question the lebel of my button in the repeat code is _open, running, and completed_ i want when the user click on runnning both open and running button is to be disable and when completed is clicked the 3 button is to be disable but am not sure how to go about this  i use the followin code at the Disable option but not workin as expected                                                                        `var value =["Open","Running","Completed"]
var status = document1.getItemValueString("Status")

if(value ==status){
 return true
}else{
 return false
}`

Answer (score 0):

In the client side events you can get event info with the global object **thisEvent**.

You can get the dom element which triggers the event with **thisEvent.srcElement**.
So I suppose you could do something like:

```
thisEvent.srcElement.style.display = 'none';
//...
```

Also in this way you avoid to do a search in the dom tree.